# Advice on using an Open-Source Real-Time Recommender System

Tags: recommender-system

We are building a web app that shows users content which they rate on a 1-5 ratings scale. Users typically spend 5 to 10 seconds per item shown before rating.

We would like to display content that is more relevant to them. There seem to be plenty of implementations of Recommender Systems, however most of them use a batch-processing, whereas we would need something that can react after every user rating.

Are there any open-source real-time recommenders that we can use or adapt to our use-case? What's the easiest way to get started with one? Any kind of advice is more than welcome.